# Avoid index wrapping in nested ng-repeat for routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an Angular app displaying 3 item columns with Bootstrap, to achieve this I'm using the following code to wrap my array of data in groups of 3:

```
examples.success(function(data) { 
  $scope.examples = data; //[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  $scope.examplesGrouped = $filter('groupBy')($scope.examples, 3);//[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]
});

$filter = ('groupBy', function() {
    return function(items, groupItems) {
        if (items) {
            var newArray = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i+=groupItems) {
                if (i + groupItems > items.length) {
                    newArray.push(items.slice(i));
                } else {
                    newArray.push(items.slice(i, i + groupItems));
                }
            }
            return newArray;
        }
    };
});
```

And then in the HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat = "examples in examplesGrouped">
    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item" ng-repeat="example in examples">
        <a ng-href="#/examples/{{ $parent.$index }}">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far so good, but when I'm trying to set my routes with `$parent.$index` it's wraped like [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2] instead of [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5].

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: What about `$parent.$index + $index` ?

Comment: `$index` is 0, that might be part of the problem...

Comment: While iterating on your first ng-repeat $index is 0, then 1, and each of your group has 3 elements inside (second ng-repeat) so you have just add your parent and current indexes

Answer (score 1):

Your parent's indexes is [0,1].
If you want your links be like:

```
<a ng-href="#/examples/0">
<a ng-href="#/examples/1">  
<a ng-href="#/examples/2">  
<a ng-href="#/examples/3">
```

etc., you have to change your template to:

```
<a ng-href="#/examples/{{ example }}"></a>
```

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hifetelebi/edit?html,output)